# MVVM. Как уведомить свойство во ViewModel о изменении Model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В своём приложении я ищу столкновения объектов...

1. Есть TextBlock на View, в который записывается количество столкновений
2. Я нажимаю кнопку на View
3. Запускается метод в Model, который считает столкновения и в конце записывает их количество в переменную
4. (проблема) Как уведомить TextBlock, о изменении переменной в Model?

**UPD:**

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    // interface implementation

    public static void Method()
    {

        // do something
        Property++; // (ошибка)нужна ссылка на этот класс
    }

    private int property;
    public int Property
    {
        get
        {
            return property;
        }
        set
        {
            property = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделать это свойство в VM с INPC и уведомлять через него

Comment: Переменная меняется в статическом методе, поэтому чтобы в нём изменить свойство нужен экземпляр данного класса, а если делать экземпляр, то свойство каждый раз разное

Comment: Уберите статику, не создавайте себе лишних проблем

Comment: @АндрейNOP не соглашусь, статика может создать не больше проблем, чем Singleton, которым обычно ее заменяют. В обоих случаях надо понимать, как оно работает, иначе принять правильное архитектурное решение практически невозможно, только если наугад.

Comment: @aepot, а я и не говорил про синглтон, просто передать нужный экземпляр параметром. Синглтон нужен когда ваш класс лезет сам в какие-то внешние ресурсы (что само по себе нехорошо), если он получает все необходимое параметрами — синглтоны не нужны

Comment: Если методу нужен экземпляр — он либо не должен быть статическим, либо получать этот экземпляр параметром. Ваш КЭП, простите, @AlanAugust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как один из вариантов, можно использовать интерфейс [`IProgress<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=netframework-4.8). Он предоставляет удобный, потокобезопасный способ отправлять промежуточные данные в процессе работы Model, например прогресс выполнения задачи. Тип передаваемых данных вы определяете сами. При этом колбэк, к которому привязан экземпляр класса `Progress` будет вызываться всегда в том потоке, в котором был создан, то есть, можно даже спокойно в колбэке модифицировать `ObservableCollection`.

В статичном классе

```csharp
public static IProgress<int> Status { get; set; }
```

Использование

```csharp
int report = 123;
Status?.Report(report);
```

Во `ViewModel` создайте колбэк для этого интерфейса с помощью класса [`Progress<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netframework-4.8), например в конструкторе VM.

```csharp
StaticModelClass.Status = new Progress<int>(status => Property = status);
```

Ну а конечный резальтат работы статичного метода я бы просто использовал в возвращаемом значении в вызывающем методе.

Comment: Спасибо. Не сразу понял как это работает. Вот ссылка с хорошим примером: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html

Answer (score 0):

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Property));
```

Comment: Добавьте разъяснения к своему ответу, чтобы он не требовал дополнительных вопросов, используя кнопку __править__.

Comment: Вы не учли возможность наличия атрибута `[CallerMemberName]` в методе `OnPropertyChanged` у автора вопроса. И проблема вопроса в другом, этот ответ не совсем по теме.

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто: нужно переместить вычисления во ViewModel. Сама модель – это только данные. Все вычисления должны происходить в ViewModel.

---

Ну или вы должны сделать метод `OnPropertyChanged` `private` -> `internal`.

Comment: Ерунду говорите. Model - это не только данные, но и органы управления и взаимодействие с другими ресурсами и вычисления (например соединение с сайтом, получение от туда данных, обработка их или отправка сообщения в чат, это логика явно не как не связана с View, а значит ей не место в VM), VM слой предназначен для связи V и M слоев, делать в нем подсчеты, не относящиеся к отображению не в его полномочиях.