# Обновить Label на форме xaml WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Нужно обновить значение Label в процессе выполнения обработчика Button.
Пробую так:

```
private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,new Action(() =>
    {
        this.ProgressBarLabel.Content = "Поиск всех файлов";
    }));
    SomeProcess();
    MessageBox.Show("Работа завершена");
}
```

Исключений не возникает. В момент появления MessageBox значение в Label обновляется. Но до этого момента, форма не отрисовывается, т.е. пока выполняется код на месте `SomeProcess` форма остается неизменной.
Можно вызвать отрисовку принудительно в момент присвоения Label значения?

Comment: _Не работает._ - ни о чем не говорит. Как вы это поняли? Исключение возникает? Какое? _в процессе выполнения обработчика Button_ - показывайте код обработчика. Вообще это странный код, непонятно, зачем понадобился диспетчер, объясните пожалуйста. Отредактируйте вопрос, сейчас в нем нет того, что позволило бы дать ответ. Можете хоть класс целиком вставить, в дополнение к тому что уже есть и рассказать кратко, что к чему в нём.

Comment: На заметку: `Label` в WPF не используют. В WPF для отображения текста используют `TextBlock`. Советую заменить.

Comment: Дополнил информацию в вопросе, Dispatcher используется в попытке обратиться к потоку запускающему форму, поскольку проблема по которой не обновляется форма я предполагаю в том что поток в котором выполняется обработка кнопки блокирует форму.

Comment: Здесь достаточно информации -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502037/where-is-the-application-doevents-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Диспетчер здесь не поможет, и вот почему: вы закидываете в UI поток работу, которая встает в очередь. А разгребаться эта очередь будет тогда, когда UI поток освободится. А освободится он тогда в данном случае, когда обработчик события полностью завершит работу.

Подозреваю, что идет работа с файловой системой. Набросаю механизм, который позволит сделать то что нужно.

Пусть `SomeProcess` это синхронный метод, работающий с какими-то структурами данных, и одновременно в других потоках с ними ничего не работает. Так же предположим, что `SomeProcess` не работает с UI. Тогда прокатит следующее решение - [асинхронный](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async) метод.

```
private async void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonStart.IsEnabled = false;
    try
    {
        ProgressBarLabel.Content = "Поиск всех файлов";
        await Task.Run(SomeProcess); // или await Task.Run(() => SomeProcess()), без разницы
        MessageBox.Show("Работа завершена");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    ButtonStart.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

`Task.Run` вереводит выполнения кода метода `SomeProcess` в другой поток. Обратите внимание, вы не можете работать с контролами из этого потока напрямую. Можно либо через диспетчер, либо с помощью `IProgress<T>`, либо надо превращать сам метод `SomeProcess` в асинхронный и избавляться от `Task.Run`, если есть такая возможность.

Как работать с `IProgress<T>`, я показывал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1423103/373567), [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1179099/373567), [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1123393/373567) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567), и еще много где.

Comment: вместо await Task.Run(SomeProcess); я использую Task.WaitAll(ListTasks); но изменений в label у меня не происходит пока обработчик события не завершит работу, но опять же в момент вызова MessageBox изменения на форме отображаются, хотя по факту событие обработчика еще не завершено- получается каким то образом в процессе выполнения обработчика все таки как то можно обновить UI.

Comment: @СергейТатевосян тогда вместо `Task.WaitAll(ListTasks);` надо `await Task.WhenAll(ListTasks);`, смысл здесь именно в await. Все проблемы с ответом из-за того что из вас код насильно надо вытаскивать. Вы же могли нормально изначально показать настоящий, а не выдуманный код в вопросе?

Comment: я не могу размещать свой код в публичном доступе согласно политике компании.

Comment: @СергейТатевосян вы же в комментарии его разместили, и кто умрет от строчки `Task.WaitAll`? вместо сферического `SomeProcess` в вакууме? Если ответ был полезен, вы можете его принять. Если бесполезен, нужно больше деталей.

Comment: @СергейТатевосян но вы меня удивили, что это коммерческий проект. Код больше похож на учебный, первых 3 дней обучения шарпу. Лейбл говорит о переходе с Winforms, обработчики событий клика про незнание об MVVM, привязках данных, командах и т.д. Проблемы с обновлением UI - об отсутствии понимания, что такое асинхронный код и многопоточное программирование. Боязнь выложить фрагмент кода - о незнании, как работает NDA, что есть секретное, а что на каждом углу в интернетах валяется. В общем, это код ученика, но не джуниора, учитесь. Ссылка на асинхронное программирование вверху, в ответе.

Comment: про MVVM, асинхронное программирование и др. мне известно- это код с инструмента, который нужно было написать на коленке для решения небольшой задачи. С плохим понимаем работы потоков согласен.

Comment: @СергейТатевосян вот, покопайтесь, может что-то полезного найдете https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+%5Bwpf%5D+%5Bmvvm%5D Наколеночный WPF как раз удобнее всего на базе MVVM писать, навык просто нужен.

Comment: Асинхронный обработчик решил все проблемы. Спасибо.